# Rearranging tabs by using the More menu's Edit button

Tags: ios

Our iOS app has more than 5 tabs in a UITabbarControlller. So, the 5th tab title is "More" as usual. When I select this tab, the list appears with the "Edit" button. After pressing the "Edit" button, I can't reorder the items on the screen. As I know, the rearrange feature should work by default without any code.

Latest Xcode 10 and iOS 12.

Comment: Are you sure that default `UITabBarController` allows to add more than 5 tabs?

Comment: :) I think this is good answer https://medium.com/@deske/hey-jason-apple-actively-discourages-that-the-tab-bar-navigation-have-more-than-5-tabs-you-will-7d70a08a8fe9

Comment: Yes. Default UITabbarController can handle tis. See this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html

Comment: It seems that this is a bug in UIKit. The problem can be reproduced with the iTunes Store app. I've reported it to Apple.